# How should I write these rewrite rules in my .htaccess file

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.domain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.domain2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.domain3\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /path/to/directory/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.domain4\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /different/path/$1 [L]
```

The first block works, but the second block gives me the following error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at admin.domain4.com.ar Port 80
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Have you checked the error log? I don't see how this would not cause a redirect loop, because the pattern `(.*)` of course matches on `different/path/...` again. But then that's true for your first block as well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first block works, but the second block gives me an Internal Server error:

Both rules/blocks have the same "issue". The first rule will only "work" if you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/path/to/directory/` that also uses mod_rewrite (perhaps to route the URL?) in order to prevent an internal rewrite loop (the probable cause of your Internal Server Error).

The easiest way to resolve this, if you are on Apache 2.4, is it simply use the `END` flag, instead of `L`. For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /different/path/$1 [END]
```

The `L` flag only stops the current round of processing, it does not stop all processing by the rewrite engine. On the second pass through the rewrite engine, the pattern `(.*)` also matches the rewritten request `/different/path/<url>` which gets further rewritten to `/different/path/different/path/<url>` etc. resulting in an endless loop, unless there is something to stop it.

Comment: Thank you very much, @MrWhite ! Your answer helped me solve the problem!!